# base64 data video upload to firebase storage failure

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code (please ignore it's ugliness):

```
const convertToVideoBlob = async  (dataURL : string, storageRef: StorageReference) : Promise<string> => {
  console.log("dataURL: ", dataURL)
  const promiseRes : any  = await fetch(dataURL);
  const blob : Blob = (await promiseRes.blob());
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = async ()=>{ 
    const newDataURL : string | ArrayBuffer = reader.result || ''
    console.log(`testing: ${newDataURL}`);
    console.log(`testing type: ${typeof(newDataURL)}`);
    await uploadString(storageRef, (newDataURL as string), 'base64');
    const videoStorageDownloadURL: string = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    console.log("videoStorageDLlink: ", videoStorageDownloadURL)
    return videoStorageDownloadURL;
    }
    // console.log("outside newDataURL: ", newDataURL);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return 'notAvailable'
}
```

where dataURL is the following string, representing a screen recording my React typescript application recorded:

```
blob:https://www.junojourney.com/a40cbd71-ea64-4bf9-b563-c6dcb34bdf53
```

in order to upload to firebase, I needed to transfer it into a Blob object and from there to to use reader.readAsDataURL(blob) which provides me of the following result within newDataURL:

```
data:video/mp4;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JAT....
```

which is from the required form of data presentation in order to use after the uploadString() method for uploading to firebase, as far as i'm aware..

but, weirdly i'm getting the following error:

> content.js:205 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found (storage/invalid-format)

and if I change the line:

```
 await uploadString(storageRef, (newDataURL as string), 'base64');
```

to

```
 await uploadString(storageRef, newDataURL, 'base64');
```

I get the following error:

```
const newDataURL: string | ArrayBuffer
Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you should cut off the `data:video/mp4;base64,` part at the start of your value. Because _those_ characters are not Base64-encoded data (and the `:` is likely the first "invalid character" it encounters here), those are just "meta data" for use as a Data URI.

Comment: don't think that's the case, as when I am uploading an image, I'm uploading it as 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....' and it works just fine ;x

Comment: To me https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string appears to very clearly suggest that you would need to use `'data_url'` instead of `'base64'` then ...?

Comment: You are correct, sir! The solution is to change the third argument of uploadString to 'data_url'. Good catch, @CBroe